# Validating schema on methods not working with Simpl-Schema in Meteor

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor, simple-schema

I am getting this error,

```
Exception while invoking method 'users_register' TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined
```

When I am execute this code,

```
Schemas.User.validate(user);
```

Here is my sample schema,

```
Schemas = {};
Schemas.User = new SimpleSchema({
username: {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z]{3,15}$/,
    optional:true
},
emails: {
    type: Array,
    optional: true
},
"emails.$": {
    type: Object,
    optional: true
},
"emails.$.address": {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
    optional:true
},
"emails.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean,
    optional:true
},
roles: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true
},
"roles.company": {
    type: Array,
    optional: true
},
"roles.company.$": {
    type: String,
    optional: true
},
profile: {
    type: Object,
    optional:true
},
"profile.first_name": {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,25}$/,
    optional: true
},
"profile.last_name": {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,25}$/,
    optional: true
},
"profile.retired":{
    type:Number,
    optional:true
},
services: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true
},
"profile.emails": {
    type: Array,
    optional: true
},
"profile.emails.$": {
    type: Object,
    optional: true
},
"profile.emails.$.user": {
    type: String,
    optional:true
},
"profile.emails.$.host": {
    type: String,
    optional:true
},
"profile.emails.$.port": {
    type: String,
    optional:true
},
"profile.emails.$.password": {
    type: String,
    optional:true
},
"profile.emails.$.status": {
    type: Boolean,
    optional:true
}
});
```

How to fix this error? What is the cause of the error? I am sure that user object is defined and have a correct properties.

Anyone can help me to fix this issue? 
Do I have missing code?

Here is my package.json part for Simpl-schema,
"simpl-schema": "0.0.3",

In /server/main.js, I added this code,

```
import '../imports/api/users';
```

In users.js file, I added this code,

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish ...
Schemas = {};
Schemas.User ... (code above)
Meteor.methods...
}
```

Comment: "simpl-schema": "0.0.3", is this a typo? If not, 0.0.3 is very early development, because the latest i 0.3.1. Try to update the npm package and see if the error remains or has been resolved.

Comment: I updated it but still not working and same issue

Comment: Can you please post more code of the file a) where you create Schemas.User (do you export it?) and b) where you define and where you call users_register

Comment: I added some code.